# Can't attach widget to my grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygobject

I'm trying to create widgets with a loop. This is what I tried :

```
def set_runways(self, airfield):
        i = 0
        for rwy in airfield['Runways']:
            frame = Gtk.Frame()
            frame.set_label('-'.join([rwy['Runway_1'], rwy['Runway_2']]))
            frame.set_shadow_type(1)

            self.runways_layout.attach(frame, (i / 2), (i % 2), 1, 1)

            rwy_layout = Gtk.Grid()
            frame.add(rwy_layout)

            # Just for testing :
            label = Gtk.Label('Hello, World')
            rwy_layout.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

I import my `runways_layout` in my `__init__` with `self.runways_layout = builder.get_object('runwaysGrid')` which is a `Gtk.Grid` and I call my function after with `self.set_runways(airfield)`. But even with this, my window doesn't show `Hello World`, I have a blank window... Why ?

I specify that my `rwy` isn't empty.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :
Okay I tried this simple thing :

```
self.runways_layout = builder.get_object('runwaysGrid')

label = Gtk.Label('Coucou')
self.runways_layout.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

And it doesn't work too... O_o

Answer (score -1):

Okay I found a solution, I have to do :

```
self.runways_layout = builder.get_object('runwaysGrid')

label = Gtk.Label('Coucou')
self.runways_layout.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

label.show()  # Add this and it works...
```

But why ?

Comment: what does it mean "why"? read the show(9 and show_all() methods from the reference and you will find out.

Comment: In my other window, I don't have to write `label.show()`. I don't understand why.

Comment: show_all() calls show() recursively on all child if it's a container, so it is sufficient to call it once on the main container (usually the main window) to show all widgets.